# Devise: How to expire all sessions of one user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I know about a way to clear the current session of a user logged into an app.

```
sign_out_and_redirect(current_user)
```

Is there a way using devise or other tools to clear all sessions of one User, if possible except the session on the current device?

Answer (score 0):

In models/user.rb: Add :timeoutable to devise modules.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :timeoutable, :timeout_in => 15.minutes
end
```

In config/initializers/devise.rb: Set the timeout parameter.

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.timeout_in = 3.hours
end
```

Note: This is applicable for all users.

Comment: I think what I am looking for is a way to manually timeout all sessions of a user triggered by a controller action for example.